# Is this a regular grammar?

Tags: regular-languages, formal-grammars, context-free

I went through a question asking me to categorize the following grammar.

$$S → AA, S → AB, A → a, A→BB, B → b, B → e$$

From the production rules, clearly it is Context-Free. But it accepts a finite set of strings.
$\{e, a, aa, ab, abb, ba, bba, b, bb, bbb, bbbb\}$
which is regular language.

So, is the above grammar regular? Though it does not follow from the rules.

Basically my question is: **Is the grammar $\{S → AA, A → a\}$ regular?.**

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is no. Whilst the **language** is finite and therefore regular the **grammar** itself is not regular. I think you already knew this as you said that this grammar's production rules are not of the form of a regular grammar.

The point here is that just because a grammar isn't regular doesn't mean the language it generates must not be regular.

Comment: I got that. But according to [wikipedia][http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_grammar], `a regular grammar is a formal grammar that describes a regular language`. Now, my grammar **is** describing a regular language. The set of rules are mentioned later, not as definition.

Comment: @Shashwat: You referring to a property of a regular grammar (it accepts a regular language), but this is not the definition of a regular language. The definition goes over the restricted left hand sides of the rules.

Comment: As the above comment says, the statement "a regular grammar is a formal grammar that describes a regular language" is not the definition of a regular grammar. That wikipedia page doesn't explicitly use the word definition at all. A better place to learn the basics and formal definitions would be a textbook. My favourite is http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Introduction_to_Automata_Theory,_Languages,_and_Computation

Comment: Ok. If restriction of rules is the definition, then my doubt is cleared. The on wikipedia, that was the first line; so I assumed it to be the definition. Thank you.

Comment: I just fixed the wording in Wikipedia.

Answer (score 0):

This a type-2 grammar (CFG) not type-3 (regular garmmar), because it consists of both left hand derivation and right hand derivation. There are CFGs which generate regular languages. That's a property.